# Angular: ng-model=value *0.5, possible?

Tags: angularjs

My code is like that:

I want that, while user modify the value of testVaalue in the first input, the second input changed automatically. Is it possible?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is this just for display purposes or do you actually want the result bound to a variable? See my answer for a display-only solution. Otherwise, what should happen if they edit the second input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it like that, but should be able to do:

```
<input type="text" readonly value="{{(value * 0.5) || 0}}" />
```

Or you could just display the result as text:

```
{{(value * 0.5) || 0}}
```

Comment: Sorry, may I ask how to do If(value==null} then 0 else {{value * 0.5}}. is it possible? Thank you again

Comment: @martinwang1985, please see my updated answer. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest declaring a new variable which can track half value.

Example

Template

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  value:{{value}} half:{{value*0.5}}!
  <br>
  <input ng-model="value" type="text">
  <input ng-model="half" type="text">
</div>
```

controller code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value = 5;
    $scope.half = $scope.value * 0.5;

    $scope.$watch('value', function() {
        $scope.half = $scope.value * 0.5;
    });
}
```